# Enviar dados de um input sem submit

Tags: php, javascript, html, input

Olá, estou programando uma table com datas, e para filtrar estou usando um input data range com 2 mini calendar. gostaria de saber como envio e utilizo essas informações sem usar submit :)

```html
<div class="calendar left">
  <div class="daterangepicker_input">
    <input class="input-mini form-control" type="text" name="daterangepicker_start" value="" />
    <i class="fa fa-calendar glyphicon glyphicon-     calendar"></i>
        <div class="calendar-time">
           <div></div>
            <i class="fa fa-clock-o glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i>
        </div>
  </div>
  <div class="calendar-table"></div>
</div>
<div class="calendar right">
 <div class="daterangepicker_input">
   <input class="input-mini form-control" type="text" name="daterangepicker_end" value="" />
   <i class="fa fa-calendar glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
     <div class="calendar-time">
          <div></div>
      <i class="fa fa-clock-o glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="calendar-table"></div>
</div>
<div class="ranges">
  <div class="range_inputs">
     <button class="applyBtn" disabled="disabled" type="button"></button> 
     <button class="cancelBtn" type="button"></button>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Gostaria de passar o daterangepicker_right e o daterangepicker_left, obrigado

Comment: Se quer enviar pro PHP sem refresh na página, terá que usar AJAX.

Comment: Tem algo mais especifico para eu dar uma olhada em Ajax?

Comment: Tem vasto material sobre AJAX aqui no site. Tenta fazer uma busca por AJAX no campo de pesquisa. Boa sorte!

Comment: Certo, Muito obrigado Sam!!! :)

Comment: Vc usa um .onChange() pra chamar uma requisição ajax.